# How to hide "Up to higher level directory" header in ProFTPD?

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

I have Debian 9 with configured ProFTPD server version 1.3.5 with anonymous access.

When I am logging to my ftp server from another PC I see **"Up to higher level directory"** header.

Is there any ways to hide it?

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to merely hide the link - or do you want to actually jail users to a specific directory? See for example [DefaultRoot](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) in the ProFTPD documentation.

Comment: @steeldriver Just want to merely hide the link.

Comment: This is unanswerable because it does not state what the FTP client, creating that user interface, is.